# Error executing a command from Java (I'm doing a Discord bot)

Tags: java, discord

I'm doing a discord command which executes a command on my Minecraft Bedrock server (I'm using Google Cloud that's why I need the "screen" package). The command executes a / say message on the server. The problem is that when I execute the command in discord the message does not appear on the server, as if the / say was not executed correctly or the command in the Ubuntu console is not executed.

```
package com.evermine.blockteam.commands;
import com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.Command;
import com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.CommandEvent;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class Csalert extends Command{
    public Csalert() {
        super.name = "salert";
        super.arguments = "[message]";
    }

    @Override
    protected void execute(CommandEvent event) {
        String args = event.getArgs();
        System.out.println("Se ha enviado el mensaje: " + args);
        try {
            String cmd = "sudo screen -S mcs -p 0 -X stuff 'say " + args + "^M'";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println (ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to debug an error when we don't have the error details.

Comment: Your command name is `salert` and not `say`

Comment: The `salert` command is for Discord and the 'say' command is which Java runs in the Ubuntu Terminal

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your main and jda-utilities configuration.